# Swift 3 - Firebase Storage putFile no result

Tags: swift, file, firebase, upload, storage

Hey there i am trying to upload files from document directory to Firebase Storage, but it simply doesnt upload them... i did research for 4 days and watched every single tutorial but i can not say why those files dont get uploaded:

My initializer just grabs one file and passes it to the actual upload method:

```
func initUploadToFirebase() {
    do {
        let file = self.getFile()

        if let file = file {
            self.uploadFile(file: file)
        }
    } catch { }
}
```

An internal helper function to retrieve a single file(actually its URL and its filename through the struct i defined)

```
func getFile() -> File? {
    var file: File?

    do {
        let fileNames: [URL] = try self.fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: self.documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
        // Simply returns the last found file
        for fileName in fileNames {
            file = File(url: fileName, filename: fileName.lastPathComponent)
        }
    } catch { 

    if file != nil {
        return file
    }

    return nil
}
```

The actual upload method where i pass all needed data:...

```
func uploadFile(file: File) {
    let storage = Storage.storage()

    // print(file) prints:
    // File(url: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/82871E8A-9919-4075-B982-9E0A019D0AF1/Documents/file11.json, filename: "file11.json")

    let ref = storage.reference().child("path").child("to").child(file.filename)

    let uploadTask = ref.putFile(from: file.url, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("upload error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        if let downloadURLString = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {
            print("downloadURLString \(downloadURLString)")
        }
    })

    uploadTask.observe(.resume) { (snapshot) -> Void in
        print("resume")
    }

    uploadTask.observe(.pause) { (snapshot) -> Void in
        print("pause")
    }

    uploadTask.observe(.failure) { snapshot in
        print("error")
    }

    uploadTask.observe(.progress) { snapshot in
        let percentComplete = 100.0 * Double(snapshot.progress!.completedUnitCount) / Double(snapshot.progress!.totalUnitCount)
        print("percentComplete \(percentComplete)")
    }

    uploadTask.observe(.success) { snapshot in
        print("uploadTask success")
        self.removeFileByName(name: file.filename)
        self.initUploadToFirebase()
    }
}
```

The struct i defined:

```
struct File {
    var url: URL
    var filename: String

    init(url: URL, filename: String) {
        self.url = url
        self.filename = filename
    }
}
```

Sooo, i created the uploadTask, setup the observers, but *resume* and *progress* are called only once... why?
The upload simply stops, and i have no explanation so far.

I turned debug messages on max, but no useful output so far...

Anybody could help me?

Thanks and Greetings!

Comment: Is the upload successful / does the completion handler for `putFile()` get called?